# R markdown ioslides incremental mode for code chunks

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How do you turn R code chunks to appear incrementally?

For example, I put the following option in the header:

```
---
...other configurations...
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    incremental: true
---
```

But the incremental mode only applies to bullets and not to the code chunks

````
## Slide 1
  * this bullet point appears first
  * this bullet point appears second
```{r eval=FALSE}
# This chunk is there from the beginning
```
````

So my question is : 
How do you make the chunk  appear after the second bullet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `.build` attribute

````
## Slide 1 {.build}
  * this bullet point appears first
  * this bullet point appears second
```{r eval=FALSE}
# This chunk appears third
```
````

There is a minor problem to this solution: On your first advancement on this slide, nothing will be displayed. You have to advance twice to make the first bullet point appear.